# A thread writes a value into a variable placed in Heap memory however the variable is not updated

Tags: c++

When A class is started through start(), A class makes receiver thread. Receiver thread's member variable 'mA' is pointing A class in constructor. After receiver is made, threadLoop() is operated. In the Loop, LocalSocket 's' is made and it's trying to make socket connection. After connection done, mSocket(mA's member variable) is updated as 's'.
 However mSocket's value is nullptr even though it's updated with 's' in threadLoop(). When send() is called, error log printed as "No socket. Cannot send request". 
 It's not occurred always. It's maybe about 1/1000 very rare.
 A class is made by "new" keyword so the memory for the class is placed in Heap. Therefore mSocket assigned by 's' in Receiver Thread's Loop should be updated I think.
 Why is the error occurred sometimes?

I have printed log mSocket's address and the address of s when issue is occurred.

// address of s when s is made.

[12:50:03.095+09][   29.405][S00:00:29Z][tcp19.925][RIL][NOTI]Pointer s = 0x816120

// After making socket connection, updating mA's mSocket

[12:50:03.095+09][   29.406][S00:00:29Z]Pointer mA->mSocket = 0x816120

// calling send() function but mSocket's value is nil

[12:50:03.934+09][   30.013][S00:00:30Z]Pointer mSocket = (nil)

[12:50:03.934+09][   30.118][S00:00:30Z]Pointer mSocket = (nil)

Here is a code.

```
class AReceiver : public Thread
{
    public:
    AReceiver(const sp<A>& a);
    ~AReceiver();
    bool threadLoop();
    //snip

    private:
    //snip
    sp<A> mA;
    //snip
};

class A : public RefBase
{
    public:
        A();
        virtual ~A();
        //snip
        void start();
        //snip

    private:
        sp<LocalSocket> mSocket;
        sp<AReceiver> mReceiverThread;
        void send(const sp<Request>& req);
        friend class AReceiver;
        //snip
};

AReceiver::AReceiver(const sp<A>& a) : mA(a){
    //snip
}

bool AReceiver::threadLoop() {
    //snip
    for(;;) {
        //snip
        sp<LocalSocket> s = new LocalSocket();
        LOGN("Pointer s = %p", (void*&) s);

        (void)s->connect(SOCKET_NAME);
        if (!s->isConnected()) {
            //snip
        }
        //snip
        LOGN("Connected to '%s' socket", SOCKET_NAME);
        mA->mSocket = s;
        LOGN("Pointer mA->mSocket = %p", (void*&) mA->mSocket);
        //snip
        for(;;) {
            //snip
            if (length < 0) {
                // End-of-stream reached
                break;
            }
            //snip
        }
        LOGN("Disconnected from '%s' socket", SOCKET_NAME);
        mA->mSocket->close();
        mA->mSocket = nullptr;
        //snip
        return true;
    }
}

void A::start() {
    //snip  
    mReceiverThread = new AReceiver(this);
    mReceiverThread->run("recv_thread");
}

void A::send(const sp<Request>& req) {
    LOGN("Pointer mSocket = %p", (void*&) mSocket);
    if (mSocket == nullptr) {
        LOGN("No socket. Cannot send request");
        return;
    }
    //snip
}
```

Comment: The code you show never calls `send`

Comment: Other code will call send(). I didn't write the code here.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. Perhaps you are calling `send` on an instance of `A` different from the one having `mSocket` assigned. Perhaps you have undefined behavior somewhere. Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: I've checked all of source code. There is no code updating mSocket.(Actually there is a code but the code is not executable) mA->mSocket = s; in threadLoop() is only updating code.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be any thread-synchronization in your code.  That is a problem, because (generally speaking) whenever two threads are accessing the same piece of data, you are required to synchronize the accesses to that shared data, otherwise your program will invoke undefined behavior and probably not do what you want (or at least, not do it reliably).

In this case, it seems that both your receiver thread and your sending thread want to access the same member-variable (`mA->mSocket`).  Since they don't lock a mutex before accessing it, undefined behavior is invoked.

A second problem is that the code appears to have a race condition -- the receiving thread creates the socket and connects it, but the sending thread tries to use it, without waiting for it to be connected first.  That means that it's quite possible that the sender thread will try to use it while it is still NULL.  To make this work properly, you need some robust way to make sure that the sender thread doesn't try to use the socket before it is ready for use (simply setting `mA->mSocket = s;` last in the receiver thread isn't sufficient, as the optimizer might change the ordering of the statements in the compiled executable, and even if it doesn't the CPU might execute the statements out of order at runtime, and even if it doesn't the L1 caches of two cores might not get synchronized when you think they will)

In short, if you're going to share data between two threads, you'll have to learn the rules for how to do it safely (they are a lot more subtle and complicated than you might imagine).  Or alternatively you can avoid the issue by using only one thread instead of two, or by giving each thread its own separate socket instead of trying to share a single socket across two threads.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I have a question one more? Why isn't mSocket in sender thread updated after a lot of minutes? If the issue is occurred then the symptom is maintained continuously. mSocket value isn't updated as 's' even though receiver thread set the value. Is the issue related to thread-synchronization?

Comment: I can't say for sure without being able to compile and run the code, but the two most likely reasons are that either the sender thread is looking at a different mSocket object than the receiver is looking at, or alternatively it is looking at the same mSocket object but because there is no mutexes/synchronization, the compiler assumes no data-sharing, and has therefore cached the NULL value in a register or L1 cache (because it "knows" the value can never be changed) and isn't synchronizing caches to find out that the other thread changed it.

Comment: When I use mutex lock()/unlock() between receiver and sender thread, the issue is occurred as well. Why does sender thread read mSocket as nullptr even though the variable is updated by receiver thread? Does each thread has separated register or cache in its own memory? The register or cache don't be updated after updating once?

Comment: If you're serializing correctly with mutexes, then thread B should see thread A's change (part of what the mutex lock()/unlock() calls do is force the synchronization of L1 caches to make sure it will).  In that case, you might want to double check that the sender thread is actually reading from the same memory location that the receiver thread wrote to (e.g. do a `printf("mA=%p\n", mA.get())` in both threads and verify that the values printed are the same)

Comment: I've already check the memory location which accessing between both threads(I 've added the source code in above code.). In the normal case, both threads are accessing same memory location. However when the issue is occurred, sender thread printed the memory location like "Pointer mSocket = (nil)".